# Add svg image as icon for Input of Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, semantic-ui

I'm using Input from Semantic UI in order to create a search input:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default ({ placeholder, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <Input
      icon="search"
      icon={<img src={searchIcon} />}
      iconPosition="left"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
};
```

It works and looks good.

The problem is that I need to change its icon with an svg image. So the svg is imported in the file and used like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import searchIcon from '../../assets/icons/searchIcon.svg';

export default ({ placeholder, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <Input
      icon={<img src={searchIcon} />}
      iconPosition="left"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
};
```

The problem is that it puts the icon outside of the input and on the right side of it.
It should be inside the input and on the left part.

[image]

There were no styling changes after the svg was added, why isn't it in the same position as the original icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely semantic-ui adding special styles when we add some icon by attribute "icon". Semantic-ui-react doesn't support custom icons. :,(

In the type declaration we can read:
`/** Optional Icon to display inside the Input. */icon?: any | SemanticShorthandItem<InputProps>`

My proposition: add some styles to CSS, like me in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-browser-10df8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
.input {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It's better to also put the css in the answer, in case the link dies

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by passing a custom component where the svg image is wrapped by an `i` tag that has a an `icon` class:

```
const CustomIcon = (
  <i className="icon">
    <img width={38} height={38} src={searchIcon} />
  </i>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Input icon={CustomIcon} iconPosition="left" placeholder="placeholder" />
  );
};
```

The benefit to this approach is that you can change the `iconPosition` without it breaking the styling with this approach.

---

To give more context the icon getting displayed at the right position is due to the styles applied to this selector: `.ui.icon.input>i.icon`. Because it expects an `i` tag the styles won't be applied if you don't wrap the image between `i` tags.